# Specification of a mixed model with nesting with lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I've been told my model wasn't statistically correct, but I'm not sure what I should do.

What I have is basically 2 **species**: A and B. 
For each species, I have 3 **replicates**: 1, 2, and 3 (=6 populations in total).
I'm applying a **treatment** with 3 levels to each population (with different individuals being used for different treatment levels).
And I'm testing the effect of the **species**, the **treatment** and of their **interaction** on the response variable.

I therefore need to nest my replicated populations within 'species', as I am interested in the 'species' effect.

**The model I wrote was:**

```
model <- lmer(response variable ~ treatment*species + (1|population), data=data)
```

with 'population' being the combination between 'species' and 'replicate', and therefore each species has 3 distinct levels of population (A1, A2, A3 and B1, B2, B3).

**This should thus be equivalent to:**

```
model <- lmer(response variable ~ treatment*species + (1|species:replicate), data=data)
```

So I thought the **nesting** was OK like this. But I got the complaint that, because I have a split-splot design, I should include the treatment*replicate(species) interaction in the model, so that populations are treated as the appropriate unit of replication.

Am I missing something, or is my model already correct with this lmer specification? As I have already nested replicate within species, I thought it was taken care of.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless there's something I don't understand, I don't think you have any nesting here... you should just do either an ANOVA or regression with dummy codes.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! I am interested in the species differences, and I tested several populations of each species in my experiment. However, I am not interested in the 'population' effect, I just want to look at the 'species' effect. By specifying my model like I did, I think I've nested 'replicate' (or 'population') within 'species'. Didn't I?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about the study design it is hard to know for sure, but if this is really a split-plot design (and only you can know that because it is a feature of the study design, not the data or the model) then your original model looks correct